# Not able to access locally stored [data.json] file while using angular project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, angular, datatable

I want to show records in `datatable`. The data are coming from `data.json` file. but I am unable to fetch data from the file.

Below is my code for accessing the data.

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('AppController', function(
      $http,
      DTOptionsBuilder,
      DTColumnBuilder
    ) {
      vm = this;

      vm.details = [];

      vm.dtOptions = vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption(
        'scrollX',
        true
      );

      vm.showDetails = function(index) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(vm.details[index], null, 4));
      };

      $http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {  // here is the file
        vm.details = response.data;
      });
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am using in `asp.net` project for implementing it.

For full reference have a look [here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/1uLySSbX9X6NGXHY)

I have done almost all thing, but I am unable to access the `data.json` file. Please suggest how can I access that.

Comment: where did you kept that file in local?

Comment: @TheParam: yes i have kept that file in local, but its not accessing it.

Comment: your data.json file should be same folder or you need to pass relative path to access it

Comment: @TheParam: same folder means where ? and I also tried with relative path like this `'~/data.json'` and still it wasn't able to access

Comment: is this issue resolved as I can see the response in on printing "vm.details"

Comment: @T.Shashwat : no the issue is not resolved. Please suggest any help

Comment: @T.Shashwat: can we do by using ajax ?

Comment: I did it using JSON server for my Angular 6 app , for Angular JS you can check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript/38254151#38254151